# Catch exception from firebase - AngularFire2

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have the following method which is located within a service, this method in particular saves a user profile nothing to exciting.

```
// Save user Profile
saveProfile(user: User): Observable<Response> {

    return Observable.fromPromise<Response>(

        this.af.database.object('/users/' + user.userId).update({
            first_name: user.first_name,
            display_name: user.display_name,
            biography: user.biography,
            intent: user.intent,
            seeking: user.seeking,
            training: user.training,
            dayDOB: user.dayDOB,
            monthDOB: user.monthDOB,
            yearDOB: user.yearDOB,
            hobbies: user.hobbies,
            last_name: user.last_name,
            gender: user.gender,
            address: user.Address
        }).then((profile: any) => {
            return new Response('Profile has been saved successfully', true);
        })
            .catch((err: any) => {
                return new Response('Unable to save profile at this time, please try again later.', false);
            }) as Promise<Response>
    )

}
```

As you can see it returns a `Promise` of type `Reponse` this is my custom class which contains a `string` and a `boolean` I populate these values based on if the update was a success or not.  I then refer the `boolean` value within my component to decide what to do next.

The issue I am experiencing is when I make this method fail it doesn't return what is specified within the `catch` section of the method, nor does it `console.log` any custom text I specify instead it just writes the following:

[image]

I have searched the `firebase` documentation but with no avail, has anyone experienced this before? did you managed to resolve it?

But seriously though why bother having a `.catch` if you can't catch these exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you have received is essentially an assertion error; it's not an error that's received from the Firebase database.

You've passed the `update` method what it considers to be an invalid argument, as the `address` property is `undefined`.

Throwing an immediate, synchronous error when an invalid argument is received is a decision that the authors of the Firebase JavaScript client have made and that is unlikely to change. You will have to ensure that you pass it valid input.

Comment: I thought they may of been the case after reading, but I thought I'll the question incase I had missed something.